# CSS HTML Make a sentence/page-element start at a new line if the end of the sentence is forced to break up by browser scaling

Tags: html, css

I got an ASP.net application, but I require some help with html and css.
So I got a bit of text followed by some buttons and some more text, now I want all these buttons to jump to the next row when one element would fall out of the page.

```
<p> Lorum ipsum ...
<asp:Button ID="Button1" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
more text </p>
```

[image]

I manipulated this last result by adding a `<br>` tag in the code.

So is there a good CSS or HTML trick to make this possible.

Comment: Enclose your buttons on some element ... an inline element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White-space nowrap should do it:

```
<p> Lorum ipsum ...
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
</span>
more text </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the buttons in a `<span>`, and set the CSS of the span to `display: block;`.

this will prevent the contents of the span (your buttons) from wrapping to the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Toss the 5 buttons into a panel element like...

```
<asp:panel style="float:left;">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
   <asp:Button ID="Button3" allotherrequiredatts=""/>
</asp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.button-group {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="button-group">
 <button ID="Button1">1</button>
 <button ID="Button2">2</button>
 <button ID="Button3">3</button>
 <button ID="Button4">4</button>
 <button ID="Button5">5</button>
</span>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxm3f9e8/)